# pg_upgrade: Sequence-Check fails

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

After pg_upgrade one check fails.

This SQL gets executed to list tables and their sequences. In comments to this question it is called "above sql".

```
SELECT S.relname, T.relname, C.attname
FROM pg_class AS S,
     pg_depend AS D,
     pg_class AS T,
     pg_attribute AS C,
     pg_tables AS PGT
WHERE S.relkind = 'S'
    AND S.oid = D.objid
    AND D.refobjid = T.oid
    AND D.refobjid = C.attrelid
    AND D.refobjsubid = C.attnum
    AND T.relname = PGT.tablename
ORDER BY S.relname;
```

Source: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fixing_Sequences

This check gets used to see of there are sequences which next-value is too low.

This check gets executed daily since several years and it did not fail since several years. This was the first time that we used pg_upgrade and not dump+restore.

Now I am a bit nervous, that some internal references are broken.

The output for auth_user_groups_id_seq is broken:

```
psql -f above.sql| grep auth_user_groups_id_seq
 auth_user_groups_id_seq    | auth_user_groups        | id
 auth_user_groups_id_seq    | modwork_emailsender     | id
```

The first line is correct, the second seems broken.

The table `modwork_emailsender` does not have the sequence `auth_user_groups_id_seq`.

Has someome an idea why above sql outputs strange values after pg_upgrade?

Versions: We upgraded from 9.3 to 10.2.

**Update**

We found a different SQL to get all sequences:

```
select s.relname as seq, n.nspname as sch, t.relname as tab, a.attname as col
from pg_class s
  join pg_depend d on d.objid=s.oid and d.classid='pg_class'::regclass and d.refclassid='pg_class'::regclass
  join pg_class t on t.oid=d.refobjid
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid=t.relnamespace
  join pg_attribute a on a.attrelid=t.oid and a.attnum=d.refobjsubid
where s.relkind='S' and d.deptype='a'
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941043/get-table-and-column-owning-a-sequence/6945493#6945493

The first query returns 140 rows (including strange results), the second 120 (without strange results).

Comment: The query you have shown only lists sequences and the columns they are related to, not any "next-values".  Also from which Postgres version to which version did you upgrade?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added the versions to the question (9.3 to 10.2). Yes, you are right, above sql does not check the next-value, that is what our check does. Above sql lists the sequences of each table, but the result seems wrong.

Comment: So how exactly are you checking the next value? There was a change in the system tables in Postgres 10 which introduced `pg_sequences` where you can query that information. The old `select * from sequence_name` does not work any longer if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think it does not matter how I check the next value.  First above sql gets executed and the result of it already contains the faulty values. Maybe the wiki page (see question) should get updated.

Answer (score 1):

we face the same problem. Apparently this issue is fixed in version 10.16. I tested 10.9,10.13,10.14,10.5 and all have the same issue.
But with 10.16 it's ok.
I don't see in release note any information on it.